# Numbering problem using \newmdtheoremenv

Tags: numbering, mdframed

I am trying to make lecture notes for a math course using `mdframed`, to have it a bit less dry than a typical research article. I have a problem obtaining a coherent numbering of Theorems, Propositions, Definitions etc.

Ideally I would like something like

> Definition 1.1.1, Proposition 1.1.2 Theorem 1.1.3 Warning 1.1.4 etc.

So far I only get 1.1.0.1 for everything.

I have seen a few hacks on StackExchange using a new dummy counter, but that does not seem to work with `\newmdtheoremenv`.

Below is what I tried. Any idea on how to fix it? Many thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[ 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     
\usepackage{geometry}         
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}   
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcounter{dummy} 
\numberwithin{dummy}{section}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[%
middlelinewidth = 2 ,%
roundcorner = 3 pt ,%
innertopmargin = -3 ,
topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor = white ,%
middlelinecolor = green!70!black ,%
]{prop}{Proposition}[dummy]
\newmdtheoremenv[%
middlelinewidth = 2 ,%
innertopmargin = -3 ,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor = white ,%
middlelinecolor =  blue!60!white ,%
]{definition}{Definition}[dummy]
\newmdtheoremenv[%
middlelinewidth = 2 ,%
innertopmargin = -3 ,
backgroundcolor = white ,%
middlelinecolor = green!70!black ,%
]{thm}{Theorem}[dummy]
\newmdtheoremenv[%
middlelinewidth = 0 ,%
innertopmargin = -3 ,
backgroundcolor = black!10!white ,%
]{example}{Example}[dummy]
\tikzset{
warningsymbol/.style={
  rectangle,
  draw=black,
  fill=white,
  scale=1,
  overlay}
}
\newmdtheoremenv[%
 hidealllines=true,leftline=true,
 skipabove=12,skipbelow=12pt,
 innertopmargin=0.4em,%
 innerbottommargin=0.4em,%
 innerrightmargin=0.7em,%
 rightmargin=0.7em,%
 innerleftmargin=1.7em,%
 leftmargin=0.7em,%
 middlelinewidth=.2em,%
 linecolor= black,%
 fontcolor=black,%
 firstextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 secondextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 middleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                           node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
 singleextra={\path let \p1=(P), \p2=(O) in ($(\x2,0)+0.5*(0,\y1)$) 
                            node[warningsymbol] {\danger};},%
]{warning}{Warning}[dummy]
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\begin{definition}
Hey
 \end{definition}
\begin{prop}
Hey
\end{prop}
\begin{thm}
Hey
\end{thm}
\begin{warning}
Hey
\end{warning}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) What is that `[dummy]` arg doing there? You need to look up the syntax for `\newtheorem`, which is what `\newmdtheoremenv` is mimicking. I would drop the `[dummy]`, use `\newmdtheoremenv[...]{prop}{Proposition}[section]`, then for all the others use `\newmdtheoremenv[...]{env-name}[prop]{Display-name}`, note where I placed `[prop]`. You can find an explanation for the `\newtheorem` syntax (there are three variants) in the manual for the `amstthm` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and thank you for posting an example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded last; `titlesec` and `sectsty` fight each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Lookup `\mdfdefinestyle` in `mdframed`, that will save you a lot of typing
2. look up the syntax for `\newtheorem`, `\newmdtheoremenv` builds on top of this syntax.

I recommend doing this:

```
\newmdtheoremenv[%
...
]{prop}{Proposition}[section] % <-- note
```

This makes a `prop` environment and a `prop` counter that is dominated by the `section` counter. Then reuse the `prop` counter on the others:

```
\newmdtheoremenv[%
...
]{definition}[prop]{Definition} % <--- note placement
```

then you get envs that follow `chapter.section.prop` throughout.

Comment: @A.Martin we've all been there